# Plotting arbitrary lines at Gviz plotTracks

Tags: r, plot, bioconductor

I would like to plot lines between two itens at different `AnnotationTrack`, or simple between two coordinates in my `Gviz`plot.

`genes`data.frame:

```
   start      end
 72529373 72690449
 75457896 75536848
 76867833 76922959
 75664651 75870596
 76958977 77024110
 72065147 72204484
 74198711 74199129
 74816044 74978179
 76758753 76864805
 77032585 77176916
 73574461 73704802
```

`library(Gviz)
library(GenomicRanges)
ideoTrack <- IdeogramTrack(genome = "bosTau6", chromosome = "chr12", fontsize=14, ucscChromosomeNames=TRUE)
axisTrack <- GenomeAxisTrack(range = IRanges(start  = c(71959908, 76756891), end = c(72409907, 77206892), names = rep("Neighborhood", 2)), fontsize=14, showId = TRUE, cex.id = 0.5, col.id = "black")
aTgenes1 <- AnnotationTrack(genes, name = "Genes", genome ="bosTau6", chromosome ="chr12", showId = TRUE, stacking ="dense")
aTgenes2 <- AnnotationTrack(genes, name = "Genes", genome ="bosTau6", chromosome ="chr12", showId = TRUE, stacking ="dense")
plotTracks(list(ideoTrack, axisTrack, aTgenes1, aTgenes2), from = 71959908, to = 77206892, sizes=c(1,1,1,1), margin=40, littleTicks = TRUE)`

This above code result in this plot:

[image]

Considering the 11 plotted genes (the fourth gene is very small and hard to see), I have the follow interaction between the genes:

`gene 1 -> gene 2 and gene 11
gene 3 -> gene 5 
gene 7 -> gene 6`

With this interaction I expect some final plot similar to this picture:

[image]

I had tried some approachs that works in normal plots but not to `Gviz` plots. Some ideas? Thank you very much!